# How does a "Proxy" work in DBus Bluez API?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I'm confused on how a proxy works in BlueZ DBus API. Currently, I'm writing a function that should read the characteristic value of a specific service.

In these function:

```
static void print_string(const char *str, void *user_data)
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

void bt_shell_hexdump(const unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    util_hexdump(' ', buf, len, print_string, NULL);
}

static void read_reply(DBusMessage *message, void *user_data)
{
    DBusError error;
    DBusMessageIter iter, array;
    uint8_t *value;
    int len;

    dbus_error_init(&error);

    if (dbus_set_error_from_message(&error, message) == TRUE) 
    {
        printf("Failed to read: %s\n", error.name);
        dbus_error_free(&error);
        return;
    }

    dbus_message_iter_init(message, &iter);

    if (dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&iter) != DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY) 
    {
        printf("Invalid response to read\n");
        return;
    }

    dbus_message_iter_recurse(&iter, &array);
    dbus_message_iter_get_fixed_array(&array, &value, &len);

    if (len < 0) 
    {
        printf("Unable to parse value\n");
        return;
    }

    bt_shell_hexdump(value, len);
    return;
}


static void read_setup(DBusMessageIter *iter, void *user_data)
{
    DBusMessageIter dict;
    uint16_t *offset = user_data;

    dbus_message_iter_open_container(iter, DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY,
                    DBUS_DICT_ENTRY_BEGIN_CHAR_AS_STRING
                    DBUS_TYPE_STRING_AS_STRING
                    DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT_AS_STRING
                    DBUS_DICT_ENTRY_END_CHAR_AS_STRING,
                    &dict);

    g_dbus_dict_append_entry(&dict, "offset", DBUS_TYPE_UINT16, offset);

    dbus_message_iter_close_container(iter, &dict);
}


static void read_attribute(GDBusProxy *proxy, uint16_t offset)
{
    if (g_dbus_proxy_method_call(proxy, "ReadValue", read_setup, read_reply, &offset, NULL) == FALSE) 
    {
        printf("Failed to read\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Attempting to read %s\n", g_dbus_proxy_get_path(proxy));
}

void gatt_read_attribute(void)
{
    GDBusProxy *proxy;
    
    const char *iface;
    int offset = 0;

    iface = g_dbus_proxy_get_interface(proxy);
    printf("Iface: %s\n", iface);
    if (!strcmp(iface, "org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1") || !strcmp(iface, "org.bluez.GattDescriptor1")) 
    {
        read_attribute(proxy, offset);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

I setup the proxy but reading the "iface" value returns NULL. Is there a way for me to set the specific interface I want the proxy for?

Can someone explain how these proxy's work?

I'm new to BlueZ DBus API. The code snippet is from BlueZ client.

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't look to be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). GATT Characteristics tend to be one of the more trickier values to get if this is your first time working with D-Bus. Maybe start with one of the simpler ones such as the [GetDiscoveryFilters](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n167) on the adapter interface. To call this you need to know  SERVICE=`org.bluez` found on the system bus. OBJECT=`/org/bluez/hci0` INTERFACE=`org.bluez.Adapter1` METHOD=`GetDiscoveryFilters`

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I haven't found many simple C examples around this topic. Most are in python. Would you be able to explain how a proxy is supposed to be used?

Comment: A proxy object is a convenient native object created to represent a remote object in another process. I would think that swapping in the GetDiscoveryFilters method in a standard D-Bus C tutorial would work. I'm not particularly familiar with C but the followings looks fairly straightforward to follow: https://www.matthew.ath.cx/misc/dbus. The four parameters for `dbus_message_new_method_call` is what I've provided above. For the `conn = dbus_bus_get` you will need `DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM` instead of DBUS_BUS_SESSION for BlueZ. On the command line use `busctl` or `gdbus` to explore org.bluez API.